# Nuget pack and install third party dependencies, not located in the bin folder

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj

I am trying to create a NuGet package that can contain and deploy third party dependencies, these are dll's and executables that my program needs to run. There are a few caveats to this issues though.

1. When installing the package the dlls need to be in one directory above the bin folder, **I can already make them install into the bin folder thats not what I need**. (This makes this question different than others I have found)
2. I would prefer using the packing via the .csproj file instead of the .nuspec if possible.

If I can't place them one level up I could probably make this work installing them into a folder within the bin folder. These requirements are a little weird **but I'm a bound by work that has already been done and don't have power to change it.**

A small example of one of the many things I have tried:

```
    <Content Include="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
        <buildAction>Embedded Resource</buildAction>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
        <PackagePath>lib</PackagePath>
        <PackageOutputPath>..\SQLite</PackageOutputPath>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
```

Comment: Hi, any update about it?

Comment: @cameroony do you use this in a .NET Core / 5+ project? There native dependency loading works a bit differently and you can use the runtime folders to make sure that the directory layout matches what .NET is looking for when resolving native dependencies.

Comment: I don't think I do right now, I would love some more information about it though. Sounds like a possible solution.

Comment: Checked its a .Net Framework project.

Comment: I think you used like a [new-sdk net472](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) class library project, right? What you shown is the pack feature for new-sdk projects. If you are using non-sdk, you should use [nuget.exe cli with nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package). Or use [msbuild -t:pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-msbuild) with what you shown to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Content Include="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
        <buildAction>Embedded Resource</buildAction>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <copyToOutput>true</copyToOutput>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(targetframework)</PackagePath>        
        <Pack>true</Pack>
   </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputPath>..\SQLite</PackageOutputPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

**Then**, re-pack your project. Before you install this new version, please delete all old nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`, then reinstall the new version. After that, re-build your main project and then you will get what you want.

**Update**

Try to pack the files into content node:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="x86\SQLite.Interop.dll">
            <buildAction>Embedded Resource</buildAction>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
       </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Then**, right-click on the Project-->**Pack**. And you should not use any other nuspec file to pack with.

Comment: This did not work, no SQLite folder created no dependencies inside of it. I created a new version of the package, deleted all the old versions of the pack from the .nuget\packages folder, and installed it to no avail.

Comment: like new-sdk net472 project? What you did cannot be a non-sdk net framwork project.  `PackageOutputPath` cannot be written under an item. It should be a property. Check my answer. Also, when you create the nupkg, Please use 7zip to unpack the nupkg file, and could you find `SQLite.Interop.dll` under `lib\net472 `folder?

Comment: `PackageOutputPath ` works for the generation path of the nupkg file when you pack your project. When you tried my method, the nupkg will be under `<solution folder>\SQLite`.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this again still not working but I think we are not on the same page. Using `PackageOutputPath` I was able to get the package to output one level up. But that is not the goal, the goal is to have the dll deploy one level up when installed. I dont think `PackageOutputPath` is what I need. It must be another property.

Comment: One clear question: you are using a non-sdk project style, please share a picture of your solution explorer and the whole csrpoj file?

Comment: From the first line of the project file.

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`